# link between .net and msn messenger

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, api, msn

Hey All,
I have a windows form application that has a textbox for input value and a button...
On the first step : on button click..i will hit the db and add the input value on the total value... 
On the second step : I will get this total value and add it on my msn messenger as a personal message....

For now I've done the first step..but before I start the second step I want to make sure if there is a way to link between .net and msn messenger...And if theres not..Ill just drop the second one...

So my real question is : I just want to know if  there is a way to interact between .net C# and msn messenger

Thanks alot =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using these libraries you can achieve what you want:

http://code.google.com/p/msnp-sharp/

> MSNPSharp is a .net library that
>   implements the MSN protocol. It's the
>   continuation of project DotMSN started
>   in 2002. Today, we have more than
>   10,000,000 users around the world
>   using services based on our library.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms630960.aspx

http://www.xihsolutions.net/dotmsn/

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Windows Live SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264574.aspx) which allows to access and update profile using REST API.